# Data from Object returns undefined In Javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to get data from mongoDB with `find()` function, which should returns objects in array form. But I cannot get the data I want in the array as it returns `undefined`.

This is the Object Array:

```json
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("635fa2d24f33bf4626211990"),
    timestamp: '2022-10-30T08:41:06.826Z',
    content: 'something here',
    published: 'false'
  }
]
```

```js
let data = await submissionSchema.find({ published: "false" }).exec();
```

I have defined `data` as the response coming out from the database, which returns the Object Array above. By `console.log(data[0])` it shows everything fine without the `[]` bracket. When I `console.log(data[0].content)`, it returns `undefined`, but I supposed it to have `something here` in the console. Anyone have clues on it? This will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out where the problem comes from. I will be describing below so that whoever might have the same problem can know where the issues comes from.

submissionSchuema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const reqString = {
    type: String,
    require: true
}

const submissionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    remark: reqString,
    published: reqString
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('submission-records', submissionSchema)
```

The issue is happening since I didn't put the data I wish to get into the Schema. Therefore, the bug can be simply fixed by adding the data you are looking for back to the schema.

```js
    const submissionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id: reqString,
        timestamp: reqString,
        content: reqString,
        remark: reqString,
        published: reqString
    })
```